# Offset() not working with my application using Yii2

Tags: jquery, html, yii2

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var x = $("#pp").offset();
    alert("Top: " + x.top + " Left: " + x.left);
  });
});
```

HTML

```
$this->registerJsFile('time/web/js/jquery.min.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);

<p id="pp">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Return the offset coordinates of the p element</button>
```

These codes i copy from another website. I had copy it to another new empty file and it works there. Can i know what is the reason and how do i make it work?

Comment: what is the error? what does alert output

Comment: @Bloodhound no error. It just doesnt show anything when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

Change the register script file path to like this.

```
<?php

$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/js/jquery.min.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()],'position'=>\yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);

?>

<p id="pp">This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Return the offset coordinates of the p element</button>
```